# Unable to locate table meta data for 'table_name'

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, mssql-jdbc

Java with MS SQL Server. While saving the data in to database I am getting the below warning -

> WARN  org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.TableMetaDataProvider - Unable to locate table meta data for 'table_name' -- column names must be provided

This warning the impacting the performance huge time. I tried with the option `generateSimpleParameterMetadata=true` but it is not helping me to resolve this error.

The configuration which I used is as below:

- Spring - 3.2.3
- sqljdbc-4.0.jar
- Java 7

### Bean Property

```xml
<bean id="abcd" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="sqlserver://localhost:1521;databaseName=abc" />
    <property name="username" value="YYYYY" />
    <property name="password" value="ZZZZZ" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="select TOP 1 * from sys.tables" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
</bean>
```

The below code which is trying to insert the data

```
public long insert(Object object) {
    simpleJdbcInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(jdbcTemplate)
        .withTableName(tableName)
        .usin‌​gColumns( col2,col3,col4)
        .usingGeneratedKeyColumns(col1);
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.put("col2", "Value2");
    parameters.put("col3", "Value3");
    parameters.put("col4", "Value4");
    Number returnId = simpleJdbcInsert.executeAndReturnKey(parameters);
    return returnId.longValue();
}
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to post relevant code.

Comment: Apologies for the unformatted code. The below code which is trying to insert the data -                        public long insert(Object object) {
  simpleJdbcInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(jdbcTemplate).withTableName(tableName).usingColumns(
    col2,col3,col4 
    ).usingGeneratedKeyColumns(col1);
  
  Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();  
   parameters.put("col2", "Value2");
   parameters.put("col3", "Value3");
   parameters.put("col4", "Value4");
    
   Number returnId = simpleJdbcInsert.executeAndReturnKey(parameters);
   
   return returnId.longValue();
  }